# Why cannot open HDR test page abnormally

Tags: cobalt

When opening the [HDR test page](https://www.youtube.com/tv?env_isVideoInfoVisible=1&&list=PLT2JIu9jdshorooZOhIZJNIxa5hAVnToP&resume), the page flow is suspended and video cannot be played properly.

From the log, `MediaSource.isTypeSupported` detection is not performed and flow cannot enter the video download procedure and the subsequent actions are suspended; but this is normal in some network environment using the same board.

Comparison analysis page request includes HTTP headers and download content and resources of the page, we didn't find anything abnormal. In addition we used debug version with some print for test, this is normal mostly, but is not normal without print. Other versions (qa/devel/gold) are not normal.

Can you provide some information for this problem?

In addition, this is normal for opening other videos of application https://www.youtube.com/tv.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the delay in response.  Are you starting Cobalt in preload mode?

There is currently a known issue ( https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67991812 ) where Cobalt fails to properly respond to isTypeSupported() queries when in preload mode, and we are working on and should have a fix for this pushed out very soon in an update to the currently released version of Cobalt 11.

Comment: Thank you for your reply which was helpful for me. I didn't start Cobalt in preload mode, but I found that the video couldn't be played normally if the javascript file (url: https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/tv-player-en_US-vfl4zL4gp/tv-player.js) was executed before the resource(url: 
https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/next?key=AIzaSyDCU8hByM-4DrUqRUYnGn-3llEO78bcxq8) which was downloaded completely. This is sequence in time problem. Are these the same problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: When will you resolve this issue in released version of Cobalt 11? Are these the same issue described last comment? Looking forward to your reply,thanks!

Comment: Can you check the linux-x64x11 config?  I was getting MediaSource::IsTypeSupported() calls when playing this video using linux-x64x11.

Comment: This issue happened only in some network environment.I think it should be the application guaranteeing sequence in time.I can not find any config which affects the sequence in time between linux-arm and linux-x64x11 platforms.How could I resolve this issue in Cobalt 11 optimally?

Comment: Eric, can you please file an issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=181120&template=699202. Make sure to provide reproduction steps and expected behavior.

Comment: I found that this issue had not reproduce in the newest released version of Cobalt 11.